# FPM/Nginx: unable to open primary script

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I'm struggling to get NGINX and PHP-FPM to talk effectively. My NGINX configuration file includes the following definition for the `api` offset:

```
    location /api {
        try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;
        gzip    off;
        fastcgi_pass    PHP:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_keep_conn off; 
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
```

and on my PHP machine I have the following Pool configuration:

```
[api]
listen = 9000
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.status_path = /status
```

I then tail the NGINX server's log file and when hitting the webserver with:

```
http://localhost/api
# or 
http://localhost/api/index.php
# or ...
http://localhost/api/resources.json
```

I can see from the NGINX server log that NGINX is correctly matching the `/api` pattern but i get the following errors:

> [error] 14#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /app/html/websites/couchbase/api/index.php (No such file or directory)"

Where the root directory on the PHP machine is `/app/html/websites/couchbase`. I'm at a complete loss on what this error really means or more importantly how to debug it from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I have tried replacing `$document_root` reference in the fast_cgi_param to hard coded values to see if it makes a difference. It does in the sense that if I point it at an incorrect directory it gives me 
a `No input file specified.` error. The only place where I get the error is when it seemingly is pointed to the right place.

---

Added this in case it helps clarify ... this is the file system at `/app/html/websites/couchbase/api` on the PHP/FPM machine.

[image: filesystem]

I created the `test.php` file which basically just echo's "Ok" back but that works no better than the primary goal of running `index.php`.

> note: I wasn't sure if execution permissions were important -- as you can see `test.php` does not have them set in the picture -- but I've tried them both ways and it appears to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about the index.php file not found in the root directory. Is it under `...couchbase/api` or is in under `.../couchbase`? In the second case you can fix this problem with a redirection.

I think you can move `try_files` outside the `location` block. I never used `$is_args` and `$args` in this kind of redirection, and I've not tested it but IMHO I think you can remove it.

I think you can fix this problem with this configuration:

```
root /app/html/websites/couchbase;

try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;

location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) $1 break;
    gzip    off;
    fastcgi_pass    PHP:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_keep_conn off; 
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

You can have a cleaner config file if you'll include the following directives:

```
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_keep_conn off;
```

inside the `fastcgi_params` file.

Comment: The try_files only applies to the `/api` pattern though so it wouldn't be appropriate to move it outside the location block. The $is_args and $args are quite useful pair. They allow you to add any remaining part of the URL to be specified as a parameter to a main script. In this case all calls to `/api/some/other/place` will call `/api/index.php` and have `some/other/place` passed in as a parameter. I've had this working as-is on OSX it's just misbehaving now on Ubuntu. :(

Comment: To your question about location of `couchbase/api` or just `couchbase` ... it is the former. I've added a picture in the description to show the file contents of that directory (in case anything jumps out).

Comment: Very, very weird. If you can, try to login as the user running nginx (or use `su`). If you copy and paste in an `ls -l` command the path to `test.php` in the error log, you see the file?

Comment: I am logged in as root -- as I am in a container in Docker -- and I can run the PHP: `php /app/html/websites/couchbase/api/test.php`, I can see the file with `ls -l` (that's the screenshot above for the directory but it works for the file too).

Comment: It is CLEARLY connecting and discerning "existing" versus "non-existing" files but then it gives an error message that indicates it can't see the file. Still, if I ask for a file that does NOT exist it reacts differently.

Comment: Let's proceed step by step: can you try with: 
    `try_files $uri /api/index.php;` ?